# BugZilla: Adding PerlConfigRequire to apache2 conf generates errors when restarting service

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, bugzilla, mod-perl

I've been following the BugZilla [installation documentation](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/configuration.html) and using mod_perl w/ apache2. Everything has gone fairly smooth and bugzilla pages appear to be getting rendered and served correctly, but I get some error message when restarting apache now, and a ton of errors showing up in the error log for the virtualhost every time a page is loaded.

This started happening after I added these two lines the docs say to add before any other mod_perl directives, so I placed it near the top of my httpd.conf.

```
PerlSwitches -w -T
PerlConfigRequire /var/www/bugzilla/mod_perl.pl
```

Now, when apache2 is restarted, I get this.

```
bugzilla01 ~: service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
    Binary file (standard input) matches
 ... waiting Return::Value is deprecated at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 13
    require Return/Value.pm called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Email/Send.pm line 11
    Email::Send::BEGIN() called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    eval {...} called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    require Email/Send.pm called at /var/www/bugzilla/Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 51
    Bugzilla::Mailer::BEGIN() called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    eval {...} called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    require Bugzilla/Mailer.pm called at /var/www/bugzilla/Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 35
    Bugzilla::Auth::BEGIN() called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    eval {...} called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    require Bugzilla/Auth.pm called at /var/www/bugzilla/Bugzilla.pm line 40
    Bugzilla::BEGIN() called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    eval {...} called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    require Bugzilla.pm called at /var/www/bugzilla/mod_perl.pl line 44
    Bugzilla::ModPerl::BEGIN() called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    eval {...} called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
    require /var/www/bugzilla/mod_perl.pl called at (eval 2) line 1
    eval 'require q/var/www/bugzilla/mod_perl.pl
;' called at /var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
```

The slew of errors I get during a home pageload

```
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: Return::Value is deprecated at lib/Return/Value.pm line 13, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Return/Value.pm called at lib/Email/Send.pm line 11, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \tEmail::Send::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Email/Send.pm called at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 51, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \tBugzilla::Mailer::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Bugzilla/Mailer.pm called at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 35, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \tBugzilla::Auth::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Bugzilla/Auth.pm called at Bugzilla.pm line 40, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \tBugzilla::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Bugzilla.pm called at /var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \tmain::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:34 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0, referer:  bugzilla.domain.net/
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: Return::Value is deprecated at lib/Return/Value.pm line 13
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Return/Value.pm called at lib/Email/Send.pm line 11
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \tEmail::Send::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Email/Send.pm called at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 51
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \tBugzilla::Mailer::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Bugzilla/Mailer.pm called at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 35
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \tBugzilla::Auth::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Bugzilla/Auth.pm called at Bugzilla.pm line 40
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \tBugzilla::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \trequire Bugzilla.pm called at /var/www/bugzilla/search_plugin.cgi line 21
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \tmain::BEGIN() called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
[Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] [error] [client 10.1.0.1] [Fri Feb 15 13:09:35 2013] Value.pm: \teval {...} called at lib/Return/Value.pm line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The Perl switch `-w` enables warnings. This is good when you're writing a new Perl script, but can be counter-productive when you're running older code that you trust to work. In this case it's spewing warnings about deprecated syntax.

Try removing `-w` and see if that cleans things up.

Comment: The errors still appear when restarting apache. Changed the line in the conf to 'PerlSwitches -T' and changed first line of mod_perl.pl to #!/usr/bin/perl -T

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a whole lot of testing as to whether this breaks anything, but in my system the errors / warnings are removed if I edit the file at:

```
/var/www/bugzilla/lib/Return/Value.pm
```

to comment out the line:

```
#Carp::cluck "Return::Value is deprecated" unless $NO_CLUCK;
```

Might need a bit of testing to check if it breaks anything, but by the looks of it that line doesn't do too much.

Comment: Small amount of testing: I can create a bug and receive the notification emails, but while that line looks to do nothing much at all, it is surely there for a reason....